# Newtonsoft deserialize json object with to many data

Tags: c#, json, json.net

**Problem**

I have a Server-Client C# program, with a RestAPI that gets data from my server in a JSON format. Now I have the problem, that the client und server often aren't on the same version after an softwareupdate. The server is sending more data than expected, which cant be stored in my class therefore newtonsoft object deserializer throws an error. The error: "Endpoint nod found".

The model on my server looks like that:

```
public class Settings : ISettings
{
    public bool IsArchiveActive { get; set; } //This is new

    public bool HasSQLStorage { get; set; }

    public string AppKey  { get; set; }
}
```

But on my client side, which doesn't have the update yet:

```
public class Settings : ISettings
{
    public bool HasSQLStorage { get; set; }

    public string AppKey  { get; set; }
}
```

My method, which deserealizes the object:

```
protected async Task<T> Get<T>(string relativeAddress)
{
    string responseBody = await Get(relativeAddress);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseBody);
}
```

**Question**
How can I configure or work around this error? I just wont to ignore this property if it isn't in my class.

---

> It should work just fine. "Endpoint not found" doesn't seem to be a mapping problem, but rather connectivity to the API issue. – silentw

I tested my project multiple times with the debugger tools an I can see, that the object has data in it. As you know with you can in the debugger see, that is in a object. Only if I convert it with the deserializer the error pops up. I haven't set any configurations on the JsonConverter.

Comment: It _should_ work just fine. "Endpoint not found" doesn't seem to be a mapping problem, but rather connectivity to the API issue.

Comment: You can try setting IsArchiveActive as nullable, however as @silentw mentioned it should not be a problem

Comment: The error you're getting has **nothing** to do with JSON serialisation/deserialisation. Please do some basic debugging **before** posting a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Might you please [edit] your post to include the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s) if any? A full [mcve] would be ideal, and maximize the chance of getting help here.

Answer (score -1):

Im guessing from your question you are having issues with the json deserialization to an object that has less fields than the inputted JSON.

Because i honestly think the errors you are experiencing are more with the API mapping considering the endpoint error and that your solution should work as long as the JsonSerializerSettings have no funky settings that you set somewhere else. The default JsonSerializerSettings should work just fine.